# Locust- how to avoid conflict when multiple virtual users performing the same post or put

Tags: post, put, locust

For write operations such as POST and PUT, is there a way to avoid conflict when multiple virtual users performing the same task?  Is there a better implementation?

```py
from locust import HttpUser, task, between
import threading

class MyUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)
    write_lock = threading.Lock()  # Threading lock for synchronization

    @task
    def perform_post(self):
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        payload = {"key": "value"}  # Your JSON payload here
        
        with self.write_lock:
            response = self.client.post("/items", json=payload, headers=headers)
    
    @task
    def perform_put(self):
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        payload = {"key": "updated_value"}  # Your JSON payload here
        item_id = 123  # Replace with the actual item ID
        
        with self.write_lock:
            response = self.client.put(f"/items/{item_id}", json=payload, headers=headers)
        
        # Process the response or log as needed
```

Comment: If preventing concurrent users to access the same api at the same time is really what you want to do then that approach seems appropriate. Not sure why you'd want to do that in a load test though :) Personally I'd use a gevent Semaphore, but maybe threading.Lock works too.